# How to start Zookeeper quorum on single windows PC

Tags: apache, apache-zookeeper

I have a Windows PC, and I wanted to start a quorum of Zookeepers for testing purposes. I have the following for my zoo.cfg file:

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=D:/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
server.1=localhost:2888:3888
server.2=localhost:2888:3888
server.3=localhost:2888:3888
```

The ZooKeeper guide then says to run it by calling something like this:

```
java -cp zookeeper.jar:lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:conf \ org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain zoo.cfg
```

How does this specify how the 3 servers are created, and where their data directories are?

Answer (score 0):

You can run zookeeper (Even multiple instances) in windows very easily using [ZookeeperRunner](https://github.com/mnadeem/ZookeeperRunner)

Refer the README file for more details, I cannot point specific section, since entire doc has to be referred.